# How to pass value as prop and insert into component as CSS style (React Native)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, immutability, react-props

I've got a reusable functional component called `CardSection`. I want to pass use different values of flex for different CardSection components.

Because of this, I want to pass the value of flex as a prop down into the CardSection component. E.g.:

`<CardSection flex='1' />`
`<CardSection flex='3' />`

However, if I try to add the key-value pair for flex into my style object, I get an error because I'm trying to set a key of `flex` with a value on an object that is meant to be immutable:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const CardSection = props => {
  styles.container.flex = props.flex;  // <---- Causes mutation error

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    position: 'relative',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'red',
  }
};

export default CardSection;
```

What's the best way to insert custom flex values in this case?

Answer (score 7):

you can do it following way

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

class Main extends React.Component {
  static getCardStyle(flexValue) {
    return StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: flexValue,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        borderColor: "#ddd",
        position: "relative",
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "red"
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <View style={getCardStyle(this.props.flex).container}>{props.children}</View>;
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Another Best way:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const CardSection = props => {


  return (
    <View style={styles.container(props.flex)}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  container: (flexValue) => { return {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    flex:flexValue
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    position: 'relative',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'red',
  }}
};

export default CardSection;
```

Answer (score 4):

you can create the stylesheet object property as function. then you called the styles property as a function.

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    containerStyle = styles.container(this.props.flex)
    return <View style={containerStyle}>{props.children}</View>;
  }
}

const styles  = StyleSheet.create({
  container: (flexValue) => {
    flex: flexValue,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    borderColor: "#ddd",
    position: "relative",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "red"
  }
});
```

Comment: This throws error in typescript since `container` key expects `ViewStyle` | `TextStyle` | `ImageStyle` types as its value.

Answer (score 2):

You should not mutate the object. Create a fresh object and assign:

```
const CardSection = props => {
  const containerStyle = { ...style.container, props.flex }

  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use composition instead of mutation:

```
style={[styles.container, { flex: props.flex }]}
```

Also, use a number for flex: `<CardSection flex={1} />`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `destructure` your `flexValue` from `props` and then pass set it to the `flex` property. You also have to move that `styleSheet` inside your component for it to have access to `flexValue`. You code will look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

const CardSection = ({ flexValue }) => {
  const styles = {
    container: {
      flex: flexValue,
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      padding: 5,
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      justifyContent: "space-between",
      borderColor: "#ddd",
      position: "relative",
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: "red",
    },
  };

  return <View style={styles.container}>{props.children}</View>;
};

export default CardSection;
```